# Python Flask server deployed on Elastic Beanstalk with AWS Internal Service Error, Logs say SECRET_KEY was never set?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-500

I am trying to deploy my flask application onto AWS using elastic beanstalk. My application runs perfectly on localhost but I have had issues with my app in deployment. I keep getting internal service errors, and when I check the logs on AWS they keep saying my secret_key was never set. Here are the logs from AWS:

> Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web: File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200
> web: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200
> web: File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web: raise value
> Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web: File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200
> web: rv = self.dispatch_request() Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200
> web: File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web:
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint Jul  7
> 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web: File "/var/app/current/application.py",
> line 94, in submit_temperature Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web:
> flash('Scores generated successfully!') Jul  7 05:25:03
> ip-172-31-10-200 web: File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py",
> line 423, in flash Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web:
> session["_flashes"] = flashes Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web:
> File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 350, in **setitem** Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web:
> self._get_current_object()[key] = value Jul  7 05:25:03
> ip-172-31-10-200 web: File
> "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py",
> line 103, in _fail Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200 web: "The session
> is unavailable because no secret " Jul  7 05:25:03 ip-172-31-10-200
> web: RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key
> was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique
> and secret.

I have researched into why it would work on local host and not in production, and previously I was setting the application.secret_key in the "if **name** == '**main**':" block, and the way Elastic Beanstalk runs my application, it skips that block. My directory structure looks like this:

```
application/
    __init__.py
static/
templates/
application.py
dbhelpers.py
rankgraph.py
scoring_algorithm.py
config.py
```

I changed where I am setting my secret key, and I have tried two different methods. Here is where I am setting my secret key.

```
from tinydb import TinyDB
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash, make_response, session
import os, time, dbhelpers, rankgraph, scoring_algorithm, config

application = app = Flask(__name__)
application.debug = True
application.secret_key = 'asfwoewb09bew'
print(application.config)
db = TinyDB('db.json')
```

I am also setting it in here because the first way still hasn't worked for me, this is my **init**.py.

```
from flask import Flask


application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object('config')
```

And here is my config.py

```
SECRET_KEY = 'dsaf0897sfdg45sfdgfdsaqzdf98sdf0a'
```

Also here is link to the repository in case I didn't provide enough information. https://github.com/human37/swmac_flask_project

Comment: Are you sure you are deploying the new version? Maybe you keep deploying old version somehow without the secret key?

Comment: I found my answer! The solution was to use Microsoft azure instead, I deployed the exact same web application with them and have had zero issues. Still confused on why it never worked on elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I can provide an answer based on your comment, or you can answer your own question if you wish?

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The cause of the issue hasn't been identified.

However, **the solution** was found in deploying the same application on `Microsoft Azure`.